# How to click on an element in listbox in selenium?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

When I wanted to test added items in Luma website
https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/olivia-1-4-zip-light-jacket.html
I can't automate the selection of size and color in separate list boxes and here inspect of element

```
 <div class="swatch-option text" id="option-label-size-143-item-167" index="1" aria-checked="false" aria-describedby="option-label-size-143" tabindex="0" option-type="0" option-id="167" option-label="S" aria-label="S" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="S" role="option" thumb-width="110" thumb-height="90">S</div>
```

I locate element in the Cart Page and write the test case
in cart Test

```
 @FindBy(id = "option-label-size-143-item-167")    
 WebElement sizeProduct;   


 public void SizeProduct() {    
    element.click();
 }


 @Test
 public void Test01_ValidSearch() throws InterruptedException {
        SeachProduct SearchObj=new SeachProduct(driver);
        SearchObj.setSearchBar(" Olivia 1/4 Zip Light Jacket");
        SearchObj.setSearchBtn();
        SearchObj.SelectProductName();
        SearchObj.SetSize();
        SearchObj.SetColor();
        SearchObj.setQuantity();
        SearchObj.AddToCart();
        String CartProductMsg = SearchObj.confirmProduct();
        assertTrue(CartProductMsg.contains("You added Juno Jacket to your shopping cart."), "Product is added successfully");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
```

This exception appears:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#option-label-size-143-item-167"}

How to handle this exception and what is the cause of it? Maybe it is because there is no wait.

[image: size of Product]

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide the implementation of the SetSize() method (side note: [methods should be in the camel case](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)), I may presume that you have a simple click inside.

Your locator looks correct, although I would recommend not to use 'id' with the numbers in it. The numbers are likely to be dynamic. 
So you are likely right when you say that the exception may be caused by the absence of the wait.

Looking at the provided website, there is some delay before the size and color sections load, when entering the product page.

Try using [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) before interacting with the element:

```
public SeachProduct setSize() {
    // consider having one instance of the WebDriverWait
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.sizeProduct)).click();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work yet and <java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set> appear for setSize.

Comment: @Salm please share the source code of the setSize method. And check the exact line which causes the exception

Comment: @FindBy(id="option-label-size-143-item-168")
   WebElement sizeProduct;  public SeachProduct SetSize() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ofSeconds(15));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.sizeProduct)).click();
            return this;
        }  error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set

Comment: @Salm, are you calling PageFactory.initElements() before interacting with the page elements?

Comment: yes, I call it.  public SeachProduct(WebDriver rdriver) {
        WebDriver ldriver = rdriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(rdriver, this);

    }

Comment: @Salm, well, I can replicate your error if I create an instance of WebDriverWait with 'null' driver. In the 1st code snippet you have "new WebDriverWait(driver, ofSeconds(15));", in the constructor you have "WebDriver ldriver = driver;" (i.e. driver is not saved to 'this' at all), what is the name of the actual driver variable? Ensure that your driver is not null during the creation on the WebDriverWait instance.